How to get Shap feature importance values for a random forest classifier at local level
I have a random forest classifier (binary) model that I'm using to run prediction on unseen test data. For each observation in the test data, I want to get the feature importance (which feature was important in making the prediction). I know that the built-in 'feature_importance_' functions in SKlearn provide feature importances at global level (importances of the features on the entire test set in general). However, I want to have the feature importance for each prediction like the following:



input_feature1
input_feature_2
model_prediction
feature importance




xxx
yyy
0
<value i want to get>


xxx
yyy
1
<value I want to get>



I've figured out how I can use Shap to get diagrams/plots (e.g., waterfall) of the feature importance at local level. I'm using the following code for this:
import shap 
explainer = shap.Explainer(model) 
shap_values =explainer(df) 
from shap import waterfall_plot 
from shap import Explainer, Explanation 
exp = Explanation(shap_values[:,:,1], shap_values.base_values[:,1], df, feature_names=feature_list) 
idx = 2 # datapoint/row to explain
waterfall_plot(exp[idx])

The code above works fine for creating the diagram. However, I don't know how to get the actual feature importance values at local level using Shap. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks
